# Creating a new entry in a sorted list in Haskell

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I implemented following code to make a new entry in a list of persons (including name and birth date). The List is sorted by the alphabet and should maintain this sorting. If a name is the same, the date defines the sorting. The function dateTurn turns the date around and works perfectly fine.

```
type Lastname = String
type Firstname = String

dateTurn :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
dateTurn (a,b,c) = (c,b,a)

new :: ((Lastname,Firstname),(Int,Int,Int)) -> [((Lastname,Firstname),(Int,Int,Int))] -> [((Lastname,Firstname),(Int,Int,Int))]
new x [] = [x]
new x (y:ys)
    |(fst x)<(fst y) = x:(y:ys)
    |(fst x)>(fst y) = y: (new x ys)
    |(fst x)==(fst y) = if (dateTurn (snd x))<(dateTurn (snd y)) then y: (new x ys) else (x:y:ys)
```

There is no error compiling the script. If I add a person tupel to an empty list it works. However, if I add to an non-empty list. The program doesn't stop working, I have to interrupt it to stop working. So, how can this be solved?

Comment: Works for me. Show the code that causes the problem.

Comment: BTW, are you aware that you are using relational operators on tuples? It might be not what you really want to do.

Comment: I failed hard. By copying my code I found a mispell. Dunno why I haven't found it the last couple of days...:D

Answer (score 2):

Since your operation is generic you should abstract it

```
insertSorted :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insertSorted x [] = [x]
insertSorted x (y:ys) | x <= y    = x: y: ys
                      | otherwise = y: insertSorted x ys
```

then, instance your types to `Ord`

```
data Person = Person { name :: String
                     , age  :: Int
                     } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord Person where
   (Person a _) `compare` (Person b _) = a `compare` b
```

then

```
print $ insertSorted (Person "Peter" 5) [ Person "John" 6
                                        , Person "Zorn" 3]
```

Comment: isn't it a bit overkill to use a guard on two cases? An `if` seems much more appropriate here

Comment: @ElectricCoffee It's a style preference. For some guards look cleaner and more generic.